# Pi 3 CDC using pyserial no data received

Tags: python, usb, pi-3

I'm trying to communicate with hardware over USB CDC and Raspberry Pi 3. When the hardware is plugged in it shows as /dev/ttyACM0 and I can open the serial port. However I am never receiving any data. The hardware is sending data and I can see it when I plug it into my PC, but when connected to the Pi nothing seems to be received.

This is a stripped down python script I've tried to use to see if any data is coming through - it will just keep waiting for data that never arrives. I've tried changing the settings and using serial.inWaiting(), but nothing seems to work.

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=None,
    )

port.setDTR(1)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    command = port.read()
    print command
```

Is there anything specific I need to do on the Pi 3 in order to receive data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering myself in case it helps anyone else. It turned out this is a problem with power - the script above works just fine and I can see the data coming through when the hardware is connected to an externally powered USB hub that connects to the Pi rather than directly into the Pi 3.